# PDO mostrando dados de conexão caso disparo do catch dentro do alert(result)

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, pdo

Porque no meu `alert(result)` do ajax o catch do `PDO` está mostrando as minhas informações de conexão ao banco de dados conforme mostra a imagem a seguir: http://puu.sh/bel2Z/e7f230ab8d.png

Código:

```
    $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost; dbname=meubanco", "meuuser", "minhasenha");
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    $sql = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO wp_contatos VALUES ('', :nome, :email, :message, :data)");
    try {
        $sql->execute(array(
            "nome"      => $_POST['nome'],
            "email"     => $_POST['email'],
            "message"   => $_POST['message'],
            "data"      => date("Y-m-d h:i:s")
        ));

        $resposta = "Sua solicitação foi recebida com sucesso. Em breve entraremos em contato.";

    } catch(PDOException $e) {

        $resposta = "Sua solicitação não foi recebida com sucesso. Favor entrar em contato pelo telefone 0800";

    }

    echo $resposta;

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Verifique seu usuário e senhas do banco de dados. Eles podem estar errados.

```
$pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost; dbname=meubanco", "meuuser", "minhasenha");
```

Para garantir que as informações da conexão não sejam exibidas, é recomendado você desativar o [`error_reporting`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.error-reporting.php) no servidor de produção

Você pode fazer isso a partir do arquivo `php.ini`, alterando a diretiva [`display_error`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.display-errors) para `off`

```
display_errors = off
```

Ou diretamente via código, com a função `error_reporting`.

```
<?php

error_reporting(0);
```

---

Outra coisa que você pode fazer para evitar a mensagem de erro é colocar a conexão com o banco dentro do bloco `try`:

```
    try {
        $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost; dbname=meubanco", "meuuser", "minhasenha");
        $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

        $sql = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO wp_contatos VALUES ('', :nome, :email, :message, :data)");

        $sql->execute(array(
            "nome"      => $_POST['nome'],
            "email"     => $_POST['email'],
            "message"   => $_POST['message'],
            "data"      => date("Y-m-d h:i:s")
        ));

        $resposta = "Sua solicitação foi recebida com sucesso. Em breve entraremos em contato.";

    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        $resposta = "Sua solicitação não foi recebida com sucesso. Favor entrar em contato pelo telefone 0800";
    }

    echo $resposta;
}
```

Nesse caso seria exibido a mensagem da exceção.

Comment: Justamente, mas se por algum motivo tiver erro nestas infos, o PDO vai mostrar todos os dados de conexão?

Comment: Caso a configuração do servidor produção esteja configurado para exibir erros esteja ativado, sim ele irá exibir.

Comment: Posso configurar no arquivo de conexão para ele não mostrar estes erros? Vai que o banco cai por exemplo, ai todo mundo fica sabendo das infos !!!

Comment: Veja a edição da minha resposta. O ideal é desativar no arquivo `php.ini` do servidor.